# calling a function when Ember starts

Tags: ember.js

I need to call a function to pre-populate some variables in my application controller as soon as the Ember application starts (i.e., before Ember renders anything).  Where's the best place to put this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what you want to do exactly, but you could use the `init` hook.

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  init : function(){
   // do your stuff
  }
});
```

But maybe this is not the best option. What kind of initialization do you want to perform? If this does not fit your case, we can look for a better option.